# Print text with original spacing

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with the following:

I want to make a page that gets a file (I upload it), reads it and outputs it in an html file.

I am uploading the file and saving the contents in a mysql DB just fine, but when I show it again, I don't have any `<br />`'s there (maybe because the file should have `\t\n` or something.

How can I make it show it like it was originally written. (In the DB I see it with the fine spacing).

Comment: his not talking about new line hes talking about apostrophe...

Comment: @SonalKhunt apostrophes? where do you read that he's talking about that?

Comment: here I don't have any 's

Comment: @Sonal Khun man, you're reading the original version, where '<br />' wasn't wrapped in backticks and therefore didn't show. I edited it 6 minutes ago

Comment: thats i am saying you put <br /> not the owner may you misunderstand

Comment: @SonalKhunt OMG, are you kidding me??? God, watch the source in edit history and see for yourself! better, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9a1dae4b-6bfe-4782-8c40-6b7066ce2719/view-source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want [`nl2br()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). It will transform all line breaks to `<br>`s

Answer (score 1):

You can either wrap inside `<pre></pre>` tags to display it as it is, or better yet use [**nl2br()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function to add html break lines `<br />` before any newline/carriage return `/r /r/n /n`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the problem isn't just in the HTML? Multiple whitespaces convert to one in web browsers. In modern browsers, you can use the CSS [white-space](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space) property to prevent that.

```
body { white-space: pre; }
```

Alternatively, you could wrap that section of HTML in a [<pre>](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/pre.html#pre) element, or you could hardcode extra spaces into `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

at time u store file data in database encode data using `htmlentities()` and at time of displaying decode it using `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: This doesn't affect white spaces, though

Comment: i give this answer bcz i understand that he cant preserve html character like quotation when displaying